# Accessing protected array object

Tags: php, arrays, protected

How do I access _connection::protected using non-object

```
Mysql Object
(
    [description] => MySQL DBO Driver
    [_baseConfig:protected] => Array
        (
            [persistent] => 1
            [host] => localhost
            [login] => root
            [password] => 
            [database] => cake
            [port] => 3306
            [flags] => Array
                (
                )
        )

    [_connection:protected] => PDO Object
        (
        )
)
```

Comment: You need a class method that returns this data. Or you can use reflection.

Comment: Hi Rizier can you please give me a sample code